# Is there a way to add the API key to my request

Tags: c#, .net, api

```
internal class SendgridSendRequest
{
    [JsonPropertyName("to")]
    public string To { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("from")]
    public string From { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to add my API key to this request but have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Where is the API key meant to go? Is it meant to be a body JSON property? A request header? A querystring param? A cookie?

Comment: Also, why not just use the existing SendGrid client?https://www.nuget.org/packages/SendGrid/

Comment: Normally the API key should be placed as a header value in an HTTP request or as a query string parameter. Not in the body of the request.